# Convert underscore sortBy to javasscript

Tags: javascript, typescript, underscore.js

I have an array which was sorted using Underscore's array function `_.sortBy()`, which I need to convert it into a vanilla JS function `.sort()`.

My problem is when I convert it to normal vanilla `array.sort()` function, my IDE (Webstorm) is throwing an error as:

> TS2362: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.

**Underscore version**

```
this.interviewDetails.data = _.sortBy(this.interviewDetails.data, function (o) {
   return new Date(o.timeslot);
});
```

**Vanilla version**

```
this.interviewDetails.data.sort((a: any, b: any) => new Date(a.timeslot) - new Date(b.timeslot));
```

[image]

Can anybody help me what's possibly wrong here?

**PS-** Please see the red underlines in `new Date(a.timeslot)` in the image above

Comment: As the error message says, the subtraction operator cannot handle objects of type [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
this.interviewDetails.data.sort((a: any, b: any) => new Date(a.timeslot).getTime() - new Date(b.timeslot).getTime());
```

Comment: Ohh yeah...Thanks